# Get nodes by content type when type key is not in root of nodes array

Tags: nodes

I am trying to get all nodes by content type. When the key is in the root of nodes array, like `[type]` I can easily retrieve it by, for example:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'page'));
```

But how do I do it when the key is not in the root, like:

```
    [title] => Test 1
    [status] => 1
    [comment] => 0
    [promote] => 0
    [sticky] => 0
    [nid] => 24
    [type] => page
    ...
    [field_worktype] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => some_value
                            )

                    )

            )
   ...
```

So, in the above example, how do I get nodes which `[field_worktype][und][0][value]` equals "some_value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x):

```
$query = new \EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'page')
  ->fieldCondition('field_worktype', 'value', 'foo');

$result = $query->execute();
if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
}
```

As an aside, the method in your OP (using the `$conditions` array) is deprecated in favour of `EntityFieldQuery` anyway, which can perform the same filters.

Comment: I saw elsewhere it was deprecated, so it seems I was lucky to be in need for something not achievable by node_load_multiple anyway :)